# How to use CriteriaQuery SUM of custom operation on some cells?

Tags: java, sql, expression, aggregate-functions, criteria-api

Consider you have table T, with fields A and B.

With regular SQL, I could do this:

```
SELECT SUM(A * (100.0 - B) / 100.0) AS D FROM T;
```

And I would get exactly what I expect.

However, I'm not sure how to do it with CriteriaQuery.

I know how to do sum over 1 field, but not how to do sum over some math expression over multiple fields in a row.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `CriteriaBuilder` interface provides the following arithmetic functions:

- addition: `sum(a, b)`
- substraction: `diff(a, b)`
- multiplication: `prod(a, b)`
- division: `quot(a, b)`

where `a` `b` parameters can be an expression and/or literal.

As for the query, here is an exampe written in a human readable form:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Number> q = cb.createQuery(Number.class);
Root<T> t = q.from(T.class);

// build SUM(A * (100.0 - B) / 100.0) expression
Expression<Double> diff = cb.diff(100.0, t.<Double>get("B"));
Expression<Double> prod = cb.prod(t.<Double>get("A"), diff);
Expression<Number> quot = cb.quot(prod, 100.0);
Expression<Number> sum = cb.sum(quot);
q.select(sum.alias("D"));

System.out.println(em.createQuery(q).getSingleResult());
```

You can also build the query as an one-liner:

```
q.select(cb.sum(cb.quot(cb.prod(t.<Double>get("A"), cb.diff(100.0, t.<Double>get("B"))), 100.0)).alias("D"));
```

I hope it clarifies your doubts.

Comment: i am getting error as "ERROR: ERROR: column "cmshcpcsco8_.nonfacility_pe_rvu" must appear in the GROUP
BY clause or be used in an aggregate function". any idea ??

Comment: @wypieprz quot method returns quotient. How to get division of two expressions?

Comment: I wonder why divide or multiply are not chosen and `quot`, `prod` are used instead... It would have saved me quite some time while looking for this