# Hibernate Criteria API: how to get the sum of all the values along two columns

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, projection

the question is very simple but I cannot get something working.
Say, I have the following table

|....**X**....|.....**A**.....|.....**B**....|
|...........|.....3.....|.....2.....|
|...........|.....1.....|.....4.....|
|...........|.....1.....|.....2.....|

I simply have to obtain the total sum of values in column A and B, so (3 + 1 + 1) + (2 + 4 + 2) = 13 and I'd like to have it with Criteria API.

I tried creating a `Projection` summing the values along A and a  `DetachedCriteria`with a similar Projection summing the values along B, but I couldn't obtain a unique result from the `DetachedCriteria` since it doesn't expose this method.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `sqlProjection`

```
.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection("sum(A + B) as sumAB", new String[] {"sumAB"} , new Type[] {Hibernate.DOUBLE}));
```

Comment: while apparently solving his problem, this anser is completely what he does **not** want to do

Comment: Based on what did you conclude that this is completely **not** what he wants to do?

Comment: `I'd like to have it with Criteria API.`

Comment: Yes, Hibernate criteria, as already said. You see that OP mentions he tried with `DetachedCriteria`. This is part of Hibernate Criteria API, and not JPA Criteria API.

Comment: I tried your suggestion adding the line `return (Long)criteria.uniqueResult();` since my method returns the overall sum but the `uniqueResult()` method returns surprisingly a `null`

Comment: @MaVVamaldo It works for me on Hibernate 4.3. Exact line used is `getSession().createCriteria(MyEntity.class)                     .setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection("sum(first_column + second_column) as sumAB", new String[] { "sumAB" }, new org.hibernate.type.Type[] { org.hibernate.type.DoubleType.INSTANCE })).uniqueResult();`. Do you return any other values with the query?

Comment: ok, my fault, sorry, I won't detail here the reason why I couldn't make it work because it's off topic. I think I'll give you the best answer check.

Answer (score -4):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21650037/351861

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Number> q = cb.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
Root<MyEntity> t = q.from(MyEntity.class);    

Path<Number> fieldB = t.get(MyEntity_.B);
Path<Number> fieldA = t.get(MyEntity_.A); 
Expression<Number> sum = cb.sum(fieldA, fieldB);
q.select(sum.alias("SUM"));

System.out.println(em.createQuery(q).getSingleResult());
```

Comment: JPA is a `standard` - for which there is a `reference implementation` like the official one, hibernate is an `alternative implementation` and since its compatible to the `standard` both will be interchangeable and maybe even work at the same time

Comment: @specializt That is true. However, a lot of people use Hibernate directly, not through JPA.

Comment: have you got any source for that extremely bold claim? Btw : "not through JPA" doesnt make any sense - Hibernate criteria **is** JPA

Comment: @specializt Just browse through SO hibernate/jpa tags and see for yourself. Hibernate is a JPA implementation, which you can use directly and not through JPA interfaces. So, instead of [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) you use [Hibernate Session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html).

Comment: hokay, so there are no sources. Thats what i thought - hey i can understand that you're a fan of hibernate (i like it myself, too) but please distance yourself from claims like "everybody uses it", the next step will be "its superior to the standard" and whatnot, you may run into professional problems some day if you keep it up

Comment: No, that means I'm not going to spend my time searching for references just to prove a point which you wouldn't accept even if I gave you a dozen of links. And another no, I'm not a big fan of hibernate, I prefer JPA where applicable. But for a lot of clients and projects JPA is just an overhead  which they don't need.